# How can I use chill-avro to load Avro GenericRecords in Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, avro, apache-spark, kryo

I tried using Avro GenericRecords in Spark, but got a java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper

https://gist.github.com/rjurney/8b90e9b709d061cc0b94

The chill project added Kryo/Avro support for Scala. How can I combine Kryo, Avro, chill and Spark to load Avros?

Answer (score 1):

chill-avro is not for loading data from the FS but for serializing inflight data. See the link below for more info

https://github.com/twitter/chill/issues/171#issuecomment-45049396